# ReactiveCocoa vs Standard Delegation?

Tags: ios, mvvm, delegates, reactive-cocoa

I wanted to understand why most tutorials and guides / articles recommend using ReactiveCocoa for communication between VC and VM or VC and M when seemingly standard delegate protocol methods would suffice and be more loosely coupled?

I work on a remote control app that listens for XML strings and then calls back through delegate to the VC and updated the View. But I was considering switching to MVVM to reduce the size of my VC's.

I dont understand why you would need to use an additional framework for communication between VC and VM as guides often recommend, when you can just implement another layer of protocol as I use currently between M and VC?

Not really a code question sorry, but i wanted a more rounded understanding of why ReactiveCoca is so heavily recommended when this can be done natively and not rely on a framework?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would say just to replace delegates with RAC signals is not an objective of Reacting programming.If you have simple view<->model communication then there is no need to switch to Reactive programming.

Reactive programming is programming with asynchronous data streams/signals where we can merge ,subscribe & react conditionally.

If we want to update some UI on response of multiple API requests performing operation on different entities, calling api one by one in sequence & follow them for completion is going to be messy. But with Reacting programming, just create signals add them in sequence. Once all operation in sequence gets completed, we can observe that finally..So Reactive Cocoa will handle all the async code overhead & it would be quite easy to add another signal in sequence ,update, merge.

http://nshipster.com/reactivecocoa/ describes all the features in quite simple way.

Comment: thanks, i just thought it would be appropriate with my remote control app as it deals heavily with delegation of a hundred parameters (for the UI) in real time XML streams both sending and receiving, the current delegate method does ok but i just thought reactivecoca may provide an enhanced feature set for this task

Comment: yes... using react ,you can save yourself from implementing multiple delegates, enhancing code flow ..defining dependencies if applicable in your case.. all in async way..

Comment: i will have to read more into it, but how could it save multiple delegates? im still going to need to pass through each parameter individually? wouldnt i just be swapping a delegate method for a reactivecocoa method?

Comment: ahh yes,, if all your input parameters are dynamic/user dependant then yes each signal has to be created separately with required input parameters but i was talking more about where you have to fetch updated data for multiple entities on basis of one entity change request & for that we have to implement delegate methods in all classes but with signals we can do it at 1 place keeping sequence as required & can even merge two signals via RACSignal’s merge method where it sends the most recent signal value.

Comment: I would say if scenarios are complicated then reactive cocoa can help you with some ready to use methods like map,reduce, merge,rac_sequence etc but if your app always needs output on basis of dynamic inputs then why to go into complexity.

Comment: Essentially the hardware sends XML strings to the app, the app splits the XML into parameters, then delegates the parameters through to the controller and view, and vice versa, the UI the user touches goes to the controller via delegate methods, is passed to the model and sent back as strings. My thought was that I could use reactivecocoa to stream the parameters between view, controller, model, as opposed to the current used delegates, but im uncertain of any advantage, it mainly came about as I was planing to use MVVM to lessen my VC's and this was a recommended communication method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149432/discussion-between-ellen-and-jcad).